# How to make change to line in .js with css

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, fancybox

I am trying to change arrow style of Fancybox in WordPress plugin called Elementor Add-ons. Support replied that I need to make change to line number 1190 of assets/js/lae-blocks.js file, add the option btnTpl, and also grab the current instance so that updates don't swipe them away.

//These are from fancybox web - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options

```
btnTpl: {
    arrowLeft:
      '<button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left" title="{{PREV}}">' +
      '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M11.28 15.7l-1.34 1.37L5 12l4.94-5.07 1.34 1.38-2.68 2.72H19v1.94H8.6z"/></svg></div>' +
      "</button>",

    arrowRight:
      '<button data-fancybox-next class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_right" title="{{NEXT}}">' +
      '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.4 12.97l-2.68 2.72 1.34 1.38L19 12l-4.94-5.07-1.34 1.38 2.68 2.72H5v1.94z"/></svg></div>' +
      "</button>"
}
```

// For current instance

```
var instance = $.fancybox.getInstance()
```

//Base64 of my new buttons are:

```
//right
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQ4IDQ4IiB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE3LjE3IDMyLjkybDkuMTctOS4xNy05LjE3LTkuMTcgMi44My0yLjgzIDEyIDEyLTEyIDEyeiIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLS4yNWg0OHY0OGgtNDh6IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIi8+PC9zdmc+

//left
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQ4IDQ4IiB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTMwLjgzIDMyLjY3bC05LjE3LTkuMTcgOS4xNy05LjE3LTIuODMtMi44My0xMiAxMiAxMiAxMnoiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMC0uNWg0OHY0OGgtNDh6IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIi8+PC9zdmc+
```

I simply lack knowledge putting it all together. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change defaults, like this:

```
$.fancybox.defaults = $.extend(true, {}, $.fancybox.defaults, {
  btnTpl: {
    arrowLeft: '<button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left" title="{{PREV}}">' +
      '<div><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></div>' +
      "</button>",

    arrowRight: '<button data-fancybox-next class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_right" title="{{NEXT}}">' +
      '<div><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>' +
      "</button>",
  }
});
```

DEMO https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/YgmBOx

Comment: Did not succeed to change Janis..  How could I do a direct change in line number 1190 of assets/js/lae-blocks.js file?
And is this where the new svg should come in place?  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>

Comment: Editing js files (from any package) is so bad idea, you would need to do that again after each update or you will loose changes. But yes, `<i>..<i>` is used for Font Awesome icons and you can replace that with anything.

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest you to try to understand why you did not succeed, it is just a copy/paste. Just make sure you add that snippet after including js file.

Comment: What about grabbing the instance to prevent  a loss on updates? (var instance = $.fancybox.getInstance() )

Comment: By updating I meant updating files to newer version of fancybox. btw, this - "grab the current instance so that updates don't swipe them away" - sounds like a complete nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to replace the content within the `<svg>` tags of arrowLeft and arrowRight with your own SVGs. This would be:

```
btnTpl: {
    arrowLeft:
        '<button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left" title="{{PREV}}">' +
        '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="48"><path d="M30.83 32.67l-9.17-9.17 9.17-9.17-2.83-2.83-12 12 12 12z"/><path d="M0-.5h48v48h-48z" fill="none"/></svg></div>' +
        '</button>',

    arrowRight:
        '<button data-fancybox-next class="fancybox-button fancybox-button-- arrow_right" title="{{NEXT}}">' +
        '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="48"><path d="M17.17 32.92l9.17-9.17-9.17-9.17 2.83-2.83 12 12-12 12z"/><path d="M0-.25h48v48h-48z" fill="none"/></svg></div>' +
        '</button>'
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Yes, that is my goal. This did not succeed to change Rayo.. Maybe targeting that line 1190 of assets/js/lae-blocks.js file is what's missing?